# how to get git log by a merged branch name

Tags: git

A git branch before merge

```
A-->B-->C-->D-->E    <-master
         \->X-->Y    <-debug
```

after merge will look like

```
A-->B-->C-->D-->E-->X'-->Y'-->M
```

then if any commit at branch `debug` and `master`, they will look like

```
A-->B-->C-->D-->E-->X'-->Y'-->M-->F      <-master
         \                   / 
          ->X-->Y-----------/---->Z      <-debug
```

Is any way to git log `Z,Y,X` without `A, B` at branch `debug`???
I try the notify `..` as `git log master..debug`, however, only get `Z`

Comment: Are you *merging* or are you *rebasing*?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `master` if you used the hash tag prior to the merge, the hashtag for `E`, you would get `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.

```
git log <commit hash tag for E>..debug
```

The command gives the differences between branches, which after the merge the only difference is `Z`. So you have to go back in history to when they were actually different.

Comment: good idea, seems work, but<br/>
<ol>
1. how to get the commit which were committed at `master`<br/>
2. if their are many branches and crossed merge, how to get the original branch tree, that is what exactly I want at this case.<br/>
<ol/>

Comment: @RobberPen You can probably use the `--no-merges` option to the `git log` command. Check the documentation for more details.